# If Statements Inside For Loops = Problems

Tags: php

For some reason my if statements don't work as expected.

```
$query = "SELECT title FROM blog";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j)
{
    if (isset($_POST['$j']))
    {
        $id  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
        $query = "DELETE FROM blog WHERE id='$id'";
        mysql_query($query);
        echo 'Deleted post.. ';
        echo '<a href="blog.php">Click here</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Failed!';
    }
}
```

What happens is that "Deleted post.." and the "link" get echoed the number of rows I have in my table blog. Only one row in my table gets deleted though which is what I want. One button gets pressed each time, so shouldn't it echo "Deleted post.." only one time and "Failed!" the rest of the times? Thanks =)

Note: I'm still new to programming, sorry if the question is stupid.

Note 2: I have many buttons on another page.. they are labeled by numbers '1, 2, 3' etc.

Comment: please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: @Tom, you will as soon as you reinstall everything after being targeted, and locked-out.

Comment: @TheBlastOne I am working on converting my code to MySQLi right now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
$_POST['$j'] // here, due to the single quotes you're
             // always testing for the literal `$j`, and not
             // the value of current loop iteration.
```

to:

```
$_POST[$j]
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables are not parsed in single quotes, you need to use double quotes. `isset($_POST["$j"]`

Also you are trying to delete the same record over and over in the loop, you're checking if  `$_POST["$j"]` is set but using `$_POST['id']`

Comment: Even that won't work.. I get "Failed!" the number of rows I have.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT title FROM blog";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    for ($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j)
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$j]))
        {
            $id  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
            $query = "DELETE FROM blog WHERE id='" .$id ."'";
            mysql_query($query);
            echo 'Deleted post.. ';
            echo '<a href="blog.php">Click here</a>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Failed!';
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're looping through $_POST[0] to $_POST[Whatever], but you're only deleting where ID = $_POST['id']. $_POST['id'] never changes. Even though you're looping over and over, you're still trying to delete the same row for each loop

Answer (score 0):

It will not work because the POST or GET or REQUEST only takes what was posted to the current page from the previous page.

You need to POST some variable to some page then only is it that you can use the `$_POST['j']`. You cannot use the variables in the current page inside POST

If you are posting `j` from some other page then I think you can use this condition instead of using like that

```
$j = $_POST['j'];

if(isset($_POST['j'])){
for($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j){
//your code
}
}
```

Hope this helps